# Determinising unambiguous automata without exponential blowup

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory

Is it possible to determinise unambiguous finite automata without exponential blowup in the number of states? I think it should not be possible but I am unable to come up with counterexamples.

Comment: I think you cannot (at least you cannot avoid super-polynomial blowup). See: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.03993

Answer (score 13):

No, the exponential lower bound for determinization holds already for unambiguous NFAs. This is obtained as follows:
Consider the alphabet $\{a,b\}$, and the language:
$$L_k=\{w\in \{a,b\}^*:\text{the $k$-th before last letter in }w\text{ is }b\}$$
It's easy to construct an unambiguous NFA for $L_k$: the NFA guesses when the $k$ before last letter is, and then proceeds with verifying that the current letter is $b$, and that there are exactly $k$ letters remaining. This NFA has size $O(k)$.

However, to construct a DFA for $L_k$, you must keep in memory the last $k$ letters, yielding at least $2^{k}$ states.

Comment: For the sake of precision, what is $w$, a string from $\{a,b\}*$?

Comment: Also this is the exact example given in the Wikipedia page for [Unambiguous Finite Automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unambiguous_finite_automaton), with some more helpful explanations there.

Comment: @chepner - Yes. I'll add a clarification

Comment: $k+1$ states suffice, so this is nearly optimal.